# Does Spring Cloud Config Server support Internationalized property file names

Tags: spring-cloud

I have a requirement to support configuration file names that have been internationalized (i.e. some_file_en_US.properties). Is this accessible in the url (i.e. /{application name}/{profile}/{label}?lang=en_US or /{label}/{application name}-{profile}_en_us.properties)

Does Spring Config Server support this?

Comment: Your title and question don't match. Are you asking about file names or property names and values or both? There's nothing preventing international characters that I'm aware of. Are you seeing problems?

Answer (score 0):

Support was added just today for generic files, but there is nothing specific about message bundles by locale.

Comment: Thanks @spencergibb I will pass this along. What is an example of something you would put in the generic file support added?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/147 and https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/171 mention logger configuration & keystores. You could put message bundles there too. You would need to pull them down on your own.